# Play Framework 1.2.4 : IllegalArgumentException when using @Catch annotation

Tags: annotations, playframework

I'm trying to use the `@Catch` annotation to catch any JAXB UnmarshalExceptions generated in my application. I tried using the code described in the [Play Documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#catch) for `@Catch`:

```
    @Catch(UnmarshalException.class)
    public static void addUnmarshalError()  {...}
```

and

```
    @Catch(value = UnmarshalException.class, priority = 1)
    public static void addUnmarshalError()  {...}
```

but neither works.

Each time I use the annotation I get the message:

```
Oops: IllegalArgumentException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

I don't think it's the code inside the method, since even an empty method body generates the exception. Is there something I'm missing in my `@Catch` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should take a throwable as a parameter:

```
@Catch(UnmarshalException.class)
    public static void addUnmarshalError(Throwable throwable)  {...}
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I was looking for an issue in the annotation call, not the method signature. Thanks!